# Use Pandas for best fit line on time based data

Tags: pandas

I have a file of data consisting of dates in column one and a series of measurements in columns 2 thru n.  I like that Pandas understands dates but I can't figure out how to do simple best fit line.  Using np.polyfit is easy but it doesn't understand dates.  A sample of my attempt follows.

```
from datetime import datetime
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

zdata = '2013-01-01, 5.00, 100.0 \n 2013-01-02, 7.05, 98.2 \n 2013-01-03, 8.90, 128.0 \n 2013-01-04, 11.11, 127.2 \n 2013-01-05 13.08, 140.0'

unames = ['date', 'm1', 'm2']

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(zdata), sep="[ ,]*", header=None, names=unames, \
parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

Y = pd.Series(df['m1'])

model = pd.ols(y=Y, x=df, intercept=True)

In [232]: model.beta['m1']
Out[232]: 0.99999999999999822

In [233]: model.beta['intercept']
Out[233]: -7.1054273576010019e-15
```

How do I interpret those numbers? If I use 1,2..5 instead of dates np.polyfit gives [ 2.024,  2.958]
which are slope and intercept I expect.

I looked for simple examples but didn't find any.

Comment: Looks like pandas depend on statsmodels and patsy libraries, so pip install them before calling pd.ols

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're doing multiple linear regression with the code you provided:

```
-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <m1> + <m2> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         5
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   3

R-squared:         1.0000
Adj R-squared:     1.0000

Rmse:              0.0000

F-stat (2, 2):        inf, p-value:     0.0000

Degrees of Freedom: model 2, resid 2

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            m1     1.0000     0.0000 271549416425785.53     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000
            m2    -0.0000     0.0000      -0.09     0.9382    -0.0000     0.0000
     intercept    -0.0000     0.0000      -0.02     0.9865    -0.0000     0.0000
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

Note the formula for regression: `Y ~ <m1> + <m2> + <intercept>`. If you want a simple linear regression for m1 and m2 separately, then you should create Xs:

```
X = pd.Series(range(1, len(df) + 1), index=df.index)
```

And make the regression:

```
model = pd.ols(y=Y, x=X, intercept=True)
```

Result:

```
-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <x> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         5
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   2

R-squared:         0.9995
Adj R-squared:     0.9993

Rmse:              0.0861

F-stat (1, 3):  5515.0414, p-value:     0.0000

Degrees of Freedom: model 1, resid 3

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             x     2.0220     0.0272      74.26     0.0000     1.9686     2.0754
     intercept     2.9620     0.0903      32.80     0.0001     2.7850     3.1390
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

It's a bit weird that you got slightly different numbers when using `np.polyfit`. Here's my output:

```
[ 2.022  2.962]
```

Which is the same as pandas' `ols` output. I checked this with scipy's `linregress` and got the same result.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to make a Series for X using df.index.